# Spark Streaming: "ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time" in Python Process

Tags: apache-spark, multiprocessing, pyspark, spark-streaming, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get the pyspark stream processing working in a `multiprocessing.Process` so I can do other things such as sending messages into the stream at the same time. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

def runStream(stream):
    stream.start()
    stream.awaitTermination(30)

topic_name = "time-analyzer"
kafka_broker = "localhost:9092"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'    

    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = kafka_broker)
    sc = SparkContext()
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
    directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic_name], {'metadata.broker.list': kafka_broker})

    parsers = directKafkaStream.map(lambda v: v)
    parsers.pprint()

    p = Process(target=runStream, args=(ssc,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    #ssc.start()
    #ssc.awaitTermination(30)
```

I have my zookeeper and kafka servers running, and when I try to run this code I get this error:

```
xxx@xxx:xxx$ xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1499813965000 ms
py4j.Py4JException: Error while sending a command.
    at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:357)
    at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:316)
    at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonTransformedDStream.compute(PythonDStream.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonTransformedDStream.compute(PythonDStream.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: py4j.Py4JNetworkException
    at py4j.CallbackConnection.sendCommand(CallbackConnection.java:138)
    at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:344)
    ... 45 more
```

However if I comment out the process code and uncomment the block after it, the code works fine. Does anyone know how I can get a stream working in a Process?